# Efficient way of generating grids

Tags: grid, combinations, permutation

Suppose that I have a 4x4 grid with positions numbered as so:

```
0  1  2  3  
4  5  6  7  
8  9  10 11  
12 13 14 15
```

And I want to put pieces in this grid, the pieces can be of any of the following 10 types: `{A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J}`

How can I efficiently generate all possible ways of putting 3 pieces in this grid(allowing for type repetition)?

Right now I have a bunch of for loops, but this doesn't look efficient nor it is scalable(if I want to put more pieces I need to rewrite the code to add for loops).

The purpose of this post is to ask if anyone knows a better way of doing this, or could at least point some papers to help me finding a solution to this problem.

Thanks!